# AWS CLI unable to add permissions to API Gateway Stage variables

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-cli

I've been trying to add stage variables to my API Gateway Lambda functions using AWS CLI,
The command that I have tried to pass is:

```
aws lambda add-permission --function-name "arn:aws:lambda:me-south-1:xxxxxxxxxxxx:function:SignInUser:ifapos" --source-arn "arn:aws:execute-api:me-south-1:xxxxxxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxxxxxx/*/GET/users" --principal apigateway.amazonaws.com --statement-id xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx --action lambda:InvokeFunction —region me-south-1
```

But I'm unable to add permissions, instead getting either:

```
Invalid choice: 'add-permission\xa0', maybe you meant:

  * add-permission
```

or:

```
aws: error: argument operation: Invalid choice, valid choices are:
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a [non-breaking space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) in your command (as the error also tells you).

Take a close look:

```
Invalid choice: 'add-permission\xa0' [...]
```

The important bit is `\xa0`. This is the "special" character that causes this issue.

Just remove it and the command will work as intended.